# Qt4 WindowsStayOnTop on LXSession

Tags: raspberry-pi, pyqt4, qt4, x11

I'm running an application on raspberry pi which uses qt4. My application have different windows, main window and dialogues. When I run my application on raspberry pi desktop it works fine, Dialog doesn't end up behind main window if i click on main window.

`Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` works fine. `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` Makes sure that the window is on top of Main Window and don't end up behind not being able to access it.

When I run my application on lxsession autostart the

`Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint`

tool doesn't work...

Any idea how it can be resolved?

What I have done so far is calling

```
Dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
```

It kinda works but the dialog is frameless.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
       MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
       MainWindow.resize(800, 480)
       MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 480))
       MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 480))
       MainWindow.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

class ControlMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(ControlMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
      self.ui = Main_Window.Ui_MainWindow()
      self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Above is my Main window setup

Below is my Dialog setup, which Im calling from MainWindow to show.

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):

   def setupUi(self, Dialog):

    Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
    Dialog.resize(492, 200)
    Dialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(492, 200))
    Dialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(492, 200))
    Dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)


class ControlMainDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(ControlMainDialog, self).__init__(parent)

    self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

I'm doing set parent in Dialog or ControlMainDialog as:

```
Dialog.setParent(Qt.QMainWindow)
```

It's not correct, any idea?

Comment: Did you set the parent on the dialog initialization, or are you only using the stay on top hint?

Comment: Haven't set parent on the dialog initialization, should it be something like *Dialog.setParent(MainWindow)"? I will try it soon!

Comment: Doesnt work, not sure how to set parent, thinking it should be correct if I initialize the Main window parent...Prob need to find some docs about this...

Comment: A parent instance is required for [window modality of a QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs). I really think there's something wrong in how you implemented it, you should better provide us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can help you with.

Comment: My bad, I have added a minimal example of my code. I hope it gives an idea what im trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I just saw that you posted documentation, which did inform me on the right path. Using exec() instead of show() allowed my dialog to be modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue, it's actually well documented here [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs]. I was using modeless Dialog by calling show() when i wanted to show my window, this allowed me to access other window and making the dialog falling behind main window, which was my issue. Using Modal dialog is showing dialog using exec(), which is explained as following:

> When an application modal dialog is opened, the user must finish interacting with the dialog and close it before they can access any other window in the application

Answer (score 0):

A modal dialog requires a parent *instance*.

Remove the `Dialog.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)` (which would reset other important window flags, such as the `Qt.Dialog` flag); create the main window first and then create the dialog *with the main window instance* as a parent.

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = ControlMainWindow()
mainWindow.show()
dialog = ControlMainDialog(mainWindow)
dialog.exec_()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`setParent` can be used even after the dialog has been ininitialized, but it will always require a parent widget instance. Read more in the [QDialog documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#details).

Comment: It's a good solution, I will look over that documentation and even remove setWindow flags, if it reset other important flags ofc. 
I don't understand what to set in the "Dialog.setParent()", the widget instance it requires, is it QMainWindow widget or?

Comment: The parent of all QObject descendants (which includes all QWidgets, thus all QDialogs) has always to be an instance of another QObject descendant. So, as shown in my example, in your case it has to be the `mainWindow` instance, but can be any other QWidget that is a top window (not a widget that is already a [sub]child of another window); it's usually better to set a parent in the object constructor, most of the times it doesn't change much if you do it later, but usually that means that some properties of the child object might be changed, depending on the classes.

Comment: I will try it again today. Yesterday I tried to do 'Dialog.setParent(QMainWindow)' and got an error, confusing. I will do 'Dialog.setParent(MainWindow)', also this MainWindow should be recognized If I'm calling/executing Dialog from another file, ofc importing first, right? I will try it when I get home and come back with an update.

Comment: Wait. You can't just "call" things out of nowhere. They are objects that exist in their scopes. It's not just about importing, it also depends on the program logic. Sorry to ask, but are you sure that you've understood the logical differences between class and instance?

Comment: No no, it's not out of nowhere. I'm calling the class which has the Dialog instance, this will execute it. I am doing the setParent in the Class and all configurations in there. I only execute the dialog in the other file, while the class and one file contain the setup and configurations.

Comment: I just saw ur instance, example. I misunderstood you.

Comment: If you found an answer by yourself, that's good. But, please forgive me, I think that the answer you provided is not satisfying enough. Maybe it's better if you edit both the question *and/or* the answer, providing the environment you are using (you never specified that you were using different files that required some import statement, for example), so that other users will be able to get *their* useful answer to a similar question.